# xcodebuild unable to run asynchronous tests using XCTestExpectation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctestexpectation

I have three asynchronous tests. All run fine when tested within Xcode, but the test case cannot be built with xcodebuild. I get 11 build errors all relating to XCTestExpectation.

Example:

```
error: unknown type name 'XCTestExpectation' @property XCTestExpectation *expectationNoImage;
```

I am using the latest command line tools (Xcode 6.1.1). xcodebuild -version correctly states that.

I am running the build with the following command

```
xcodebuild -project myprojasync.xcodeproj -scheme testScheme -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 clean test | ocunit2junit
```

Everything runs perfectly with the same command if I comment out the async tests and their counterparts.

Edit: Here's one of the test methods.

```
@property XCTestExpectation *expectationPass;

-(void)testTaskPass{

//Expectation
self.expectationPass = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Testing Async Works"];

[self.asyncTask getInfo]; //asynchronous call

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:nil];
}  

-(void)returnedFrom:(NSURL *)url with:(UIImage *)image{
    if([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"http://correcturl.com"]){
    [self.expectationPass fulfill];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, pls put the test method here, it will be easier to visualize what is going on...tkx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the issue was actually that while I had the 6.1 tools within XCode. I had older tools still on my computer and for whatever reason even though my xcode-select pointed to the correct ones, it was trying to use the older tools. Uninstalled the older tools and everything works now :)

Answer (score 1):

it is not clear when u fulfill the expectation. I see that you have:

```
-(void)returnedFrom:(NSURL *)url with:(UIImage *)image;
```

There's a fulfill there but is not clear to me when you call it.

This is how I would do it:

```
@property XCTestExpectation *expectationPass;

-(void)testTaskPass{

   //Expectation
   self.expectationPass = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Testing Async Works"];

   //asynchronous call
   [self.asyncTask getInfo:^(){
       // some Assertions here...
       [self.expectationPass fulfill];
   }];

   [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error){
       XCTAssertNil(error, "Error");
   }];
}
```